# Ember (1.9.0) CollectionView + external sorting library disappearing items

Tags: ember.js

http://jsbin.com/jikurimeyo/2/edit?html,js,output

When you drag 'one' to the end of the list and then remove 'three' the last 2 elements disappear.

This is the latest version of Ember, am I missing something about managing external DOM manipulation or does this seem like a bug?

Comment: I don't think its a bug, probably Sortable is messing up Ember's internals when it changes the positions of the DOM elements without notifying it. You can investigate this by starting a `debugger` in Ember.ContainerView packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js:1409